# Resume cached fluid bake in python

Tags: python, physics, fluid-simulation

I am finding this useful to clean up some fluid cache files and re-simulate from where I change the flow on a single source that I'm adjusting for Initial Velocity. The flow is set to be enabled on frame 800, so I see no need to re-do the simulation from frame 1.

If I use the GUI, I am able to continue (re-do) a fluid bake from where my cache files have left off, by deleting the cache files outside blender and setting the current frame to 800 and click on Play from that point.  I can see the new cache files start to appear within a minute using this technique.

I want to automate this (baking) in python, and I'm using the following:

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_current=799
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for object in scene.objects:
        for modifier in object.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == 'FLUID':
                if modifier.fluid_type == 'DOMAIN':
                    print("Baking fluid for ", object.name)
                    object.select_set(True)
                    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = object                    
                    print("  Baking data for ", object.name)
                    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data()
                    print("  Baking mesh for ", object.name)
                    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_mesh()
                    print("  Baking noise for ", object.name)
                    #bpy.ops.fluid.bake_noise()
                    print("  Baking particles for ", object.name)
                    bpy.ops.fluid.bake_particles()
                    bakedItemCount+=1
... etc
```

But it seems that my `frame_current=799` is being ignored.  Blender is grinding away, apparently spending time stepping through the already simulated, cached frames (1-799), as it slowly does in the GUI if I set current_frame to 1 in the GUI and play from frame 1.

I'd like your input on how to speed blender to start at frame 799-ish.   I also tried the `-s` on the blender command line but alas this is probably only for rendering.